# offline tileserver for whole planet

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, mapnik, tilemill, mbtiles

I'm trying to build an offline tileserver using the `planet.osm.pbf` files found [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/) and I've hit a bit of a scaling problem.

My first attempt was to render some of this data into an `.mbtiles` file and serve it with `Tilemill`.  This works very well up to a certain zoom level, but then the size of the pre-rendered tiles explodes. My guess at the appropriate solution is to pre-render tiles down to some reasonable zoom level and then have a mechanism for rendering the remaining zoom levels on the fly. Alternatively, I understand that there are vector-based tiles that are (maybe?) always efficiently rendered on the fly in the browser (`mapbox gl` does this, I think).

Does anyone know of the best approach to setting up an offline tileserver at this scale?  A lot of the other answers I've seen deal with how to serve tiles for a specific city or state, but I'm not coming up with much for showing the whole planet.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Alternatively, if there are other formats in which the planet-wide data is available other than `planet.osm.pbf` I'm definitely open to hearing about it -- I'm not tied to the specific datasource, I'm just trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For task of that scale you will need Mapnik
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik

1. install mapnik and renderd https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/ (TileMill as I know uses mapnik, so check maybe you already have it)
2. import your data into PostGIS (for whole planet it may take a several days and about 300G of hard drive space)
3. convert your style from TleMill for mapnik
4. now you have your own render server

Also there is a docker container with some styles and mapnik+postgis+osm2pgsql playing in one band. https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dkiselev/nik4web/ May be it could be helpful for you.